# Transformer Primetouch screen response: is this normal?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, asus-eee-pad-transformer, touchscreen

I recently got a transformer prime and just want to check whether the odd responses in the touchscreen are normal or not.

Below I have attached a screen shot from Photoshop touch. The odd snakeing down the diagonal strokes makes me think something is not quite right about the tablets touch screen. Is this normal on other primes?

[image: Photoshop touch screen shot]

Comment: I'm assuming you're moving (or think you're moving) your finger in smooth curves?

Comment: Yes, as smooth as I can. I have also had the same results using a wacom bamboo stylus. Also the tablet was running in its "performance" mode, to ensure it wasn't CPU skips that were causing the issue.

Comment: Obviously not a scientific test, as I used my hand and not yours, but Photoshop Touch on a Xoom I get far smoother lines, with none of that odd wobblig on the big strokes.

Comment: I can confirm this same issue. It happens there are several people complaining about the same exact thing. When the lines are diagonal, you get waviness, for some reason. Example #1
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1440092 Example #2
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1441180 I'm wondering if Asus knows that this problem is around.

Answer (score 2):

THIS IS the ASUS answer I received!  Really, sweep it under the carpet.  I cannot return this unit, is already over the return period time....

I own a TF 201, I installed SketchBook Pro.

I also have an Ipad 2 (from work) with the same same software.

My issue, is the Transformer Prime, does not respond very well compare to the Ipad.

I truly wonder if this is a problem with the Transformer since all application even Skitch do not produce very smooth response be it with finger or capacitive stylus. Rendering drawings on the prime, results in broken lines, circles which are not complete and always feel like the line has to "catch up" to your finger or stylus. This is not a problem I experience on the Ipad.

Can you please advise if this is "working" as designed or is this a case of a screen not working to par (and how to resolve or exchange)? This is truly proving to be a disappointment has drawing is a very important feature to me. More so since this works flawlessly on the Ipad.

My unit, has the latest firware updates;
IML74K.WW_epad - 9.4.2.15-20120221
Touch Panel : MXT- 2.0 build -170

> Thank you for choosing ASUS products.
>
> We apologize for the late response. It is only till your email sent to
>   Satisfaction-CA, I have picked up the case. Regarding to the problem
>   that you were/are having, I ams afraid ASUS will be limited to support
>   your product since this is a third party software, and you might have
>   to contact the vendor for technical support. Given the fact that iPad
>   and Prime are equipped with different OS, it is possible that the
>   experience of using a complete identical software might varies. We are
>   very sorry for the inconvenience induced in this matter. Please let us
>   know if further questions and concerns raised. Your kind understanding
>   is greatly appreciated.
>
> Tom Wang
>
> ASUS Canada 802 Cochrane drive, unit 2 Markham, Ontario, L3R 8C9
>   Canada Fax: 905-489-2717

Tom, are you kidding?

This is the same with ANY drawing apps, or note taking application.  The ASUS screen is not as responsive and not responsive enough.

I'm using Android designed software for ICS, other users are doing the same and having the same issue.

You cannot really tell me this is working as designed?

Even user with the original Transformer are saying their older screen was more responsive compared to the new one!

Come on ASUS be responsible and add this to the list of must have fixes!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these tests,

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHpfkI6l1-0

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dk9nwIRngvk&feature=related

it is normal for touchscreens to respond like that.
iOS devices have some kind of secret algorithm that "knows where you meant to touch", therefore, the test seems smoother on the iPhone...

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that this issue can be softened at an application level. (Changing the device's reported position itself would be better but not possible without changing the kernel as far as I was informed).

This is an example of some diagonal lines I've drawn myself (can't post image):

http://s9.postimage.org/9hr2fsddb/primedef.png

I tried to simulate this deformation effect (left), and then I applied a function to every "detected" point to try to put it in the right location (right). This is the outcome:

http://s9.postimage.org/6ctxtdmkv/primedeformation2.png

I posted this idea in forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1516716 . 
The writepad app dev said he would try this but he has been really busy so I still haven't any reports on whether this works or not.